# Timeout on Google Apps Script "maximum execution time"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Hi, I have a script that changes the visibility on calendar events. The script reaches the maximum execution time. Is there any way I can prevent this? Or, even better, right now the script goes through each and every event, even if they are already set to private. Could I modify the script so that it only checks the current day?

```
function ChangeCalendarEvents() {


      //Room1
    var mycal = 'comp.com_38353134313283637333434@resource.calendar.google.com';
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
      var events = cal.getEvents(new Date('January 1, 2014 00:00:00 CST'), new Date('December 31, 2014 23:59:59 CST'), {visibility: 'default' || 'public'});
      for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
        events[i].setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE);
      }


      //Room2
      var mycal2 = 'comp.com_319373936383633831343039@resource.calendar.google.com';
    var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal2);
      var events = cal2.getEvents(new Date('January 1, 2014 00:00:00 CST'), new Date('December 31, 2014 23:59:59 CST'), {visibility: 'default' || 'public'});
      for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
        events[i].setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following modified version of your code.

It has the following changes:
1. mycal is now an array (makes code easier to read, easier to add / remove calendars to modify)
2. start / end boundaries are now variables (by default, start = today, end = today + 1 week)

This should run pretty quickly. If you are still having problems, set a debug point at "for (var i=0..." and tell me how many elements are in the events array.

```
function ChangeCalendarEvents() {
  var mycal      = ['comp.com_38353134313283637333434@resource.calendar.google.com',   //Room 1 
                    'comp.com_319373936383633831343039@resource.calendar.google.com'], //Room 2
      start      = new Date(),
      end        = new Date(start.getYear(),start.getMonth(),start.getDate()+7);
  for (var index = 0; index < mycal.length;index++) {
       var cal   = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal[index]),
          events = cal.getEvents(start, end, {visibility: 'default' || 'public'});
      for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
            events[i].setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE);
          }
      };
    }
```